# How to load external js in angular Universal load children

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I want to load an external js lib file when a specific module is loaded using loadChildren

```
 { path: 'abc',  loadChildren: () => import('./abc/abc.module').then(m => m.abcModule) },
```

I am using angular universal version 15

document.getElementsByTagName("script") can not be used because the document object is only available when platformBrowser is true.  This is unacceptable because this script should be loaded even when google crawler hits the site.

so how can I load this js file in the loadChildren function ?

Answer (score 0):

Loading external JavaScript files in an Angular Universal application can be a bit tricky because you don't have access to the document object directly in the server-side rendering context. To load external scripts during the server-side rendering process, you need to use the TransferState service to pass data between the server and the client.

Here's an example of how you might achieve this:

- In your module, create a service to handle the loading of the external script:

```
// external-script.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TransferState, makeStateKey } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ExternalScriptService {
  private scriptLoadedKey = makeStateKey<boolean>('scriptLoaded');

  constructor(private transferState: TransferState) {}

  loadScript(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      // Check if the script is already loaded on the client side
      const scriptLoaded = this.transferState.get(this.scriptLoadedKey, false);

      if (scriptLoaded) {
        resolve();
        return;
      }

      // Load the script on the server side
      // You may need to adjust the script URL and attributes based on your needs
      const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
      scriptElement.src = 'path/to/your/external-script.js';
      scriptElement.onload = () => {
        this.transferState.set(this.scriptLoadedKey, true);
        resolve();
      };
      scriptElement.onerror = (error: Event | string) => {
        reject(error);
      };

      document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
    });
  }
}
```

- In your module, use the ExternalScriptService to load the script before the module is loaded:

```
// abc.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ExternalScriptService } from 'path-to-your/external-script.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./abc/abc.module').then(m => m.AbcModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  providers: [ExternalScriptService],
})
export class AbcRoutingModule {
  constructor(private externalScriptService: ExternalScriptService) {
    // Load the external script when the module is instantiated
    this.externalScriptService.loadScript().then(() => {
      console.log('External script loaded successfully');
    });
  }
}
```

Please note that the exact implementation might vary based on your specific requirements and the structure of your application. Make sure to adjust the script URL, attributes, and error handling according to your needs.